# Different charset whitelist for each region in Tesseract

Tags: tesseract

Tesseract supports specifying a charset whitelist and blacklist, and it also supports specifying regions using the UZN file format from UNVL.

However, I need now to scan a document with 2 regions, one with digits only, one with normal text. Can I specify different charset for the 2 regions **without executing Tesseract twice**?

If not, I will probably be trying to modify the code of the `UNICHARSET` class to do it somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally did it by using SetImage()/SetRectangle() from the Base API. For each rectangle I run this code:

```
    api.SetRectangle(left, top, width, height);
    api.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", whitelist.c_str());
    char *s = api.GetUTF8Text();
    printf("%s", s);
    delete s;
```